# Create a event (like on tap) for a Custom widget

Tags: flutter

I am creating my custom widget in which I am using `RaisedButton`
I want to export `onTap` event from `RaisedButton` to parent widget. How can I do that?

Comment: Why you wanna export the event? You wanna modify the parent widget if a `onTap` event gets triggered?

Comment: i am creating a custome designed button to use at multipal pages.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Create a custom widget:

```dart
class MyCustomWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final VoidCallback? onTap;

  const MyCustomWidget(this.text, {
    Key? key,
    this.onTap,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: onTap,
      child: Text(text),
    );
  }
}
```

---

Usage:

```dart
MyCustomWidget(
  'My button',
  onTap: () {},
)
```

Comment: i want pass parameter in callback function

Comment: For that you need to use `Function` instead of `VoidCallback`

Comment: my code only worked after putting `onPressed: widget.onTap(),` (with the () at the end)

Comment: how can I return something like button text.